# display product names in order list admin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, nopcommerce

I wanted to modify admin Orders List view to work like Current Carts page i.e. have a details view where if you open details view of an order it shows the items ordered within the order there itself.

To achieve this I did the following changes in the code, but it isnt working!

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Grid<OrderModel>()
                    .Name("orders-grid")
                    .ClientEvents(events => events
                        .OnDataBinding("onDataBinding")
                        .OnDataBound("onDataBound")
                        .OnComplete("onComplete"))
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords'       
  value='<#= Id #>' class='checkboxGroups'/>")
                        .Title("<input id='mastercheckbox' type='checkbox'/>")
                        .Width(50)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });

                        columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                            .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(x.CustomerEmail, "Details",  
    "Order", new { id = x.Id }, new { }))
                        .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Edit/<#= Id #>\">" + 
    T("Admin.Common.View").Text + "</a>");

                        if (!Model.IsLoggedInAsVendor)
                        {
                            //a vendor does not see order details such statuses or 
  totals
                            columns.Bound(x => x.OrderStatus);
                        }
                        columns.Bound(x => x.PaymentStatus);
                        if (!Model.IsLoggedInAsVendor)
                        {
                            //a vendor does not see order details such statuses or 
  totals
                            columns.Bound(x => x.ShippingStatus);
                        }
                        columns.Bound(x => x.CustomerEmail);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.StoreName);

                        columns.Bound(x => x.CreatedOn);
                        if (!Model.IsLoggedInAsVendor)
                        {
                            //a vendor does not see order details such statuses or 

  totals
                            columns.Bound(x => x.OrderTotal)
                                   .FooterTemplate(
                                       string.Format("<div><strong>{0}:</strong></div>" 
    +
                                                     "<div>{1}: <span id=\"aggregator-
 profit-block\"></span></div>" +
                                                     "<div>{2}: <span id=\"aggregator-
 tax-block\"></span></div>" +
                                                     "<div>{3}: <span id=\"aggregator-
    total-block\"></span></div>",

  T("Admin.Orders.Report.Summary").Text,

 T("Admin.Orders.Report.Profit").Text,
                                                     T("Admin.Orders.Report.Tax").Text,

  T("Admin.Orders.Report.Total").Text));
                        }
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                            .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.View").Text, 
  "Edit", new { id = x.Id }))
                            .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Edit/<#= Id #>\">" + 
   T("Admin.Common.View").Text + "</a>")
                            .Width(50)
                            .Centered()
                            .Title(T("Admin.Common.View").Text);
                    })
                     .DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
                        Html.Telerik().Grid<OrderModel.OrderProductVariantModel>()
                        .Name("cartitems-grid-<#= Order Id #>")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(sci => sci.FullProductName)
                            .Template(sci => Html.ActionLink(sci.FullProductName, 
    "Edit", "ProductVariant", new { id = sci.ProductVariantId }, new { }))
                            .ClientTemplate("<a href=\""+ 
      @Url.Content("~/Admin/ProductVariant/Edit/") + "<#= ProductVariantId #>\"><#= 
     FullProductName #></a>");
                            columns.Bound(sci => sci.Quantity).Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(sci => sci.UnitPriceInclTax).Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(sci => sci.SubTotalInclTax).Width(100);
                          //  columns.Bound(sci => sci.Store).Width(150);
                          //  columns.Bound(sci => sci.UpdatedOn).Width(100);
                        })
                        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                        .Select("GetOrderDetails", "Order", new
                            {
                                OrderId =
                                    "<#= OrderId #>"
                            }))
                        .ToHtmlString()
                    )
                    )
                    .Pageable(settings => 
     settings.PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("OrderList", 
      "Order"))
                    .EnableCustomBinding(true))
```

I am trying to get data from partial class of OrdersModel via OrdersProductVariantModel to show this data

I modified OrderController to include the following method

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public ActionResult GetOrderDetails(int OrderId)
{
    if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCurrentCarts))
    return AccessDeniedView();

    //   var customer = _customerService.GetCustomerById(customerId);
    //  var cart = customer.ShoppingCartItems.Where(x => x.ShoppingCartType == ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart).ToList();

    var order = _orderService.GetOrderById(OrderId);
    var orderDetails = order.OrderProductVariants.ToList();

    var gridModel = new GridModel<OrderModel.OrderProductVariantModel>()
    {
         //   Data = cart.Select(sci =>
            Data = orderDetails.Select(sci =>
            {
               // decimal taxRate;
               // var store = _storeService.GetStoreById(sci.StoreId);
                var sciModel = new OrderModel.OrderProductVariantModel()
                {
                    Id = sci.Id,
                  //  Store = store != null ? store.Name : "Unknown",
                    ProductVariantId = sci.ProductVariantId,
                    Quantity = sci.Quantity,
                    FullProductName = sci.ProductVariant.FullProductName,
                //    UnitPrice = _priceFormatter.FormatPrice(_taxService.GetProductPrice(sci.ProductVariant, _priceCalculationService.GetUnitPrice(sci, true), out taxRate)),
                //    Total = _priceFormatter.FormatPrice(_taxService.GetProductPrice(sci.ProductVariant, _priceCalculationService.GetSubTotal(sci, true), out taxRate)),
                   // UpdatedOn = _dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUserTime(sci.UpdatedOnUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc)
                };
                return sciModel;
            }),
           // Total = cart.Count
        };
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = gridModel
        };
    }
```

However, when I run the code it stops even loading the order as there is no activity on the lists page at all!

Can someone please help me in solving this problem?

Thanks
Amit.